# Reading serial port using cat gets me nothing, but screen works?

Tags: osx, serial-port

I'm trying to read a serial port using cat, but I get absolutely nothing, using

```
cat /dev/tty.usbserial-FTZ29YKM
```

I'm assuming that even if the baudrate is wrong, I should at least get some garbage data.  However, it works if I try to open a screen session with:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-FTZ29YKM 115200
```

I want to use another utility to simultaneously write to the serial port, so I can't just use screen.  How would I make cat, or some similar utility, work?

Comment: If the baud rate is wrong you may or may not get back garbage.  Most of the time you'll get nothing back.

Comment: What is the output of `stty -a /dev/tty.usbserial-FTZ29YKM`?